# How to make Scrapy pipeline process items in parallel way

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

Here is my settings:

```
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 64
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN = 100
```

I want to download `requests` and process `response` by `spider` in parallel way. 
But it doesn't work. Because it is sent to the `Item Pipeline` which processes it through several components that are executed sequentially!

Comment: That is usually not a problem, because network latency is usually much much worse than the CPU time required by pipelines. Or callbacks, for that matter. If you are doing CPU-heavy stuff in pipelines, consider using Twisted’s `deferToThread` to run CPU-heavy stuff in a different thread.